# Drupal - form or content type and general how to do it?

Tags: drupal

(I know there is a module, but I'm trying to learn on my own)

I basically want some kind of form or page where I create a form for an administrator.

So, the administrator can fill in the question and can add more than one right answer. Sorta like a multiple choice question with more than one answer.

The user will go ahead and answer the question.

Do, I create a content type? Do I use form api instead. Not sure at this moment how to go about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [Quiz](http://drupal.org/project/quiz) module provides tools for authoring and administering quizzes through Drupal. A quiz is given as a series of questions, with only one question appearing per page. Scores are then stored in the database.

Comment: yeah, thanks!I already looked at the quiz module. But I want to able to show the answer right away after the question is answered.

Comment: And then continue to the next question

Answer (score 0):

From what I get, you can create a custom drupal module and use form api for creating Multipage forms and add pragmatically add validaters for adding you correct result before moving to the next page/form.

Writing a simple. Hope this helps and contact if you need help.